# How to read text file from server and store in dictionary using c#

Tags: c#, sockets, dictionary, client, server

I'm supposed to receive a text file from the server and then read the file and store it in a dictionary in the client.

I've read the file but I'm not sure how to take out the information in the file and store it in a dictionary from here.

My text file contains details like these:

Amy;10.30;100;$7

Bendy;4.30;100;$9

Bobby;3.20;80;$7

**Client code**

```
private static void loadMovies()
{
        try
        {
            byte[] data = new byte[1024];
            writer.WriteLine(BROWSE);
            writer.Flush();

            while (true)
            {
                data = ReceiveMovieData(server);
                MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(data);
                loadMovies();
                break;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //textBox1.Text = ex.Message;
        }
    }

    private static byte[] ReceiveMovieData(Socket s)
    {
        int total = 0;
        int recv;
        byte[] datasize = new byte[4];

        recv = s.Receive(datasize, 0, 4, 0);
        int size = BitConverter.ToInt32(datasize, 0);
        int dataleft = size;
        byte[] data = new byte[size];


        while (total < size)
        {
            recv = s.Receive(data, total, dataleft, 0);
            if (recv == 0)
            {
                break;
            }
            total += recv;
            dataleft -= recv;
        }
        return data;
    }
```

Comment: Do you have a question?

Answer (score 0):

I assume that your data is delimited by semi-colon `;` and each record is divided by break line. So my suggestion is to parse the data by:

- Reading each record per line
- Splitting the columns by `;` (semi-colon). there are methods available when your data is already a `string` processing it like this:

  ```
  string s = "abc; 123";
  string[] columns = s.Split(';');
  ```
- Then properly casting each column to its proper data type.
- And then storing it to a custom `Dictionary` that would match your requirement